# What is the difference between ValueError and IndexError?

Tags: python, exception

I am learning about arrays and linked lists. When I wanted to take look at the implementation of a singly linked list, I found [this](https://github.com/TheAlgorithms/Python/blob/master/data_structures/linked_list/singly_linked_list.py) on GitHub. If you take a look a the implementation, you will probably notice that people used `IndexError` and `ValueError` interchangeably for the same purpose: for telling the user that the index they have provided doesn't have a valid value. So this is the source of confusion. Could someone please shed some light on the difference and when to use them?

Furthermore, I would appreciate it if someone explained the following sentence from Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html?highlight=valueerror#ValueError)

> ... and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError.

Comment: If the exception results from someone specifying an invalid value for an index, then IndexError is more appropriate.

Comment: Aha. That's my understanding. But, my question is why does an implementation with many stars on GitHub use these both exceptions, rather than, as you said, just the single one?

Comment: That question should be posed to the authors of the code. They are the ones in a position to answer it.

Comment: I thought there is a reason for doing it in the way they did. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Index Error is for wrong indexs, while Value Errors are for when a string might be empty, etc.

Comment: It would be very nice if you could add a few examples on where to use which error. From my personal experience, its quite often hard to choose which Exception you want to throw at a particular case.